# php millisecond isuse between server and local

Tags: php, datetime

When I execute the code below on the server it gives me the answer below:

```
$date1='1367276400000';

$date2=date('Y-m-d',($date1/1000));

echo "Date -> ".$date2."-->"."\n";
```

**Answer:** `Date -> 2013-04-29-->`

when I execute same code locally it gives me a different  answer:

**Answer:** `Date -> 2013-04-30-->`

Local server php timezone is: *Asia/Calcutta*

production server timezone is: *UTC*

How can I get the same output on both servers?

Comment: Simply set your server timezone too (i.e. `Asia/Calcutta`).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

Put `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` at the beginning of your script.

**Explanation**

This will cause date function to show date in the UTC timezone regardless of the what the system timezone is set to.

You could force timezone to be Asia/Calcutta same way but since you mentioned that UTC is the timezone on the production environment I think you should stick with UTC. You usually have more control over you local environment than the production server environment. This might be important if your PHP script at some point will have to interact with some other services running on the production server that use system timezone.

Comment: it would be better, if you add this as a comment

Comment: It's not a comment. It's an answer. And better than the other ones as it brings local environment in line with production server environment, not the other way around.

Comment: Its a comment because you are not providing any example as you see 
mohammad mohsenipur's answer

Comment: Please direct me to a written guideline that code snippet is required for a response to be considered an answer.

Comment: See [How to Write a Good Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: I still don't see your point. The link you gave just shows some tips on how to improve your answer, not the strict requirements of what your response should have to be considered an answer. I provided exact code and indicated the place where it should be placed for the problem to be solved. If you think my answer is lacking please improve it by editing it. I post as comment when I merely suggest directions where one should look in my opinion to find the answer. I use answers only when I provide an actual answer to the posed problem. As in this case.

Comment: @KamilSzot While it is an answer, a little more explanation as to why your method is superior would be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

use `date_default_timezone_set` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php first of code like

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
 $date1='1367276400000';
 $date2=date('Y-m-d',($date1/1000));
 echo "Date -> ".$date2."-->"."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

So this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date = date("d-m-Y");  
print 'The date is: ' . $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `timezones`

```
$today = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
$today->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
echo today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```